# Resultado similar a un SELECT NULL,*

Tags: mysql, select, null

Al igual que se puede hacer algo así:

```
SELECT *,NULL FROM tabla;
```

Me gustaría hacer esto:

```
SELECT NULL,* FROM tabla;
```

Obviamente da un error de sintaxis pero, ¿habría alguna forma de conseguir ese mismo efecto para no tener que escribir todos los nombres de los campos en la consulta?

Comment: En SQL Server `SELECT NULL,* FROM tabla;` funciona correctamente. Puedes probar con `SELECT NULL as Campo,* FROM tabla;`

Comment: Sí, el alias fue una de mis primeras opciones, pero no hubo suerte :( ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una facil es

```
SELECT NULL, A.* FROM tabla as A;
```

es facil y simple

Comment: Y sin usar alias para la tabla también funciona, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se me acaba de ocurrir esta solución, igual es poco elegante, pero ahí va:

```
CREATE TABLE nula(
  campo bool
  );
INSERT INTO nula VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM nula,tabla;
DROP TABLE nula;
```

Toda alternativa será bien recibida